# ggplot2: Different width of bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataset is at the link [dataset in txt](https://easyupload.io/rgai5n)

```r
ggplot(vojvodina2016, aes(x=uz, y=per1000, fill=grupa)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,5,15, 25,35,45,55,65,75,85),
                     label = c("0", "5", "15","25", "35", "45","55", "65", "75","85+")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: graph]

However, it seems that bars are different width.

Comment: You can add `color = "white"` to your `geom_bar()`, it may solve your problem. `geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge', color = "white")`

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing different widths? It just looks like screen artifacts from when you're showing a lot of bars smashed up together. Adjusting the width of bars or using `position_dodge2` for some padding might help, but honestly it seems like a way of visualizing this data that will be difficult to read at this size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with the scale of your variables.

Sample code:

```
ggplot(vojvodina2016, aes(x=uz, y=per1000,  width=0.85, fill=grupa)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,5,15, 25,35,45,55,65,75,85),
                        label = c("0", "5", "15","25", "35", "45","55", "65", "75","85+")) + 
      theme_bw()
```

Plot:

[image]

You can use  `facet_wrap (~ groupa)`

[image]

Also try to add "dodge" separetly

```
ggplot(vojvodina2016, aes(x=uz, y=per1000,  width=0.85, fill=grupa), position="dodge") +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  #facet_wrap(~grupa)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,5,15, 25,35,45,55,65,75,85),
                    label = c("0", "5", "15","25", "35", "45","55", "65", "75","85+")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This is awsome. Your post save a day.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and obtained a graph with equal width for all bars. There is no line in your code suggesting it should be otherwise. Try printing it out with a different **size/resolution**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. All anwers were halpful.